# Redirect functions not working anymore on Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress

I've setup a WordPress site and I have come across a very strange problem. I have set up a login page for subscribers and if the login is unsuccessful I want the page to redirect back to my custom login page and not the wp-login.php page. To work around this I have added the following code to wp-login.php.

```
    //  if ( $shake_error_codes && $wp_error->get_error_code() && //in_array( $wp_error->get_error_code(), $shake_error_codes ) )
//      add_action( 'login_head', 'wp_shake_js', 12 );

//I have replaced the code on line 55 with the following
  if ( $shake_error_codes && $wp_error->get_error_code() && in_array( $wp_error->get_error_code(), $shake_error_codes ) ){
header("Location: index.php/login?login_error=1"); exit;
   }
```

The redirect is not working at all, I have also used the wp_redirect()
function instead of header() and it still does not redirect.

It's not only the wp-login page that gives this problem, I have also tested the redirects on other pages. For example on my home template page home.php I added the following code right at the top of the page for the sake of testing.

```
$location = 'http://www.google.com';
 wp_redirect($location);
```

And also

```
$location = 'http://www.google.com';
header("Location: $location");
```

I cannot see why any of the redirects would not be working, there are no errors given so its like the redirects are being blocked. What could possible be causing this problem, please assist, thanks

Just an update, I have added the following code to the top of the page

```
if(headers_sent()){echo "sent";}
```

It prints out 'sent' so the headers have already been sent, looking into this

Comment: Is the page shown or is it just a blank page?  What do you see when there's suppose to be a redirect?  Have you tried any debug methods such as a var_dump('test') before the header() to make sure it's getting there?  Have you set PHP to show errors?

Comment: There are no errors shown, the redirects are just ignored and the page loads as normal, no , yes PHP is set to show errors, I will get an error if I add any invalid code. I will try the debug methods that you have mentioned and get back to you thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 ); exit; ?>
```

Notes

The HTTP/1.1 status code 302 is a temporary redirect. If the page has moved permanently, use the HTTP status code 301.

Comment: bizzare I have tried your solution but it does not work unfortunately, you might have pointed me in the right direction. On Friday I changed the site's temp url to the domain name. I dont know if this might be the cause.

Comment: charl please clear you host or create a new folder and then install a clean wordpress ,  then use the wp_redirect again and tell me the result.

Comment: unfortunately this site is already live and very busy so a clean install is gonna be last resort, I will keep you updated on my progress debugging this error

Comment: ok , just test the functionality by creating a simple php file in  a separate folder.good luck